# Symfony insists on writing debug logs to dev.log despite my configuration

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have configured Symfony to use the rotating_file type of logging with Monolog, where I have configured it to write at the info level to a daily log file, eg. dev-2024-02-22.log. While this works, Symfony insists on writing tons of debug level logs to the generic dev.log file, and within minutes this log file fills up to over 4GB in size. I have configured my monolog.yaml like so:

```
monolog:
    channels: ['database_activity']
    handlers:
        main:       
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: info
            max_files: 10
            formatter: monolog.formatter.json
            channels: [ "!event", "!doctrine" ]
            
        console:
            type: console
            process_psr_3_messages: false
            level: info
            channels: ["!event", "!doctrine", "!console", "!database_activity"]
```

How do I get Symfony to stop writing to dev.log altogether?

Answer (score 0):

I found there is another setting in the generic monolog.yaml that is called "nested" and was using debug instead of info. I will see if removing this will ultimately prevent the dev.log from being written to.